# Is "forwent" used much?

Tags: verbs, word-usage, past-tense, simple-past

I see "forgo" used quite a bit, and "forgone" is quite common too.  I can't say I've ever seen or heard of "forwent" and in fact, I had to look it up to make sure it even was a word at all.  Is it used much?  Is there an alternative that is more common?

I suspect it's more common to say, for example, "I decided to forgo treatment" rather than "I forwent treatment."  But why?

Comment: I can imagine it being used in some humorous verse, to make it properly rhyme.

Comment: I may have used it once or twice in a jocular sense, but I don't think I've ever heard anyone else use it.  (And for some reason many people don't find my "jocular sense" all that jocular.)

Comment: I used it in a paper I wrote in law school. The professor made a little tick mark beside it, but as far as I know didn't dock me. I'd looked it up to make sure I was right, but I imagine it was the first time he'd seen it used.

Answer (score 9):

Apparently not. There are only four citations for it in the whole of the OED, the most recent being dated 1596. The reason for its being seldom used is the same reason why other words are seldom used: they serve no useful purpose.

Comment: However, the past tense of *forego* is *forewent*, which seems to mean the same thing, and was used as recently as 1884!

Comment: @Matt - Are you sure "(they) was used as recently as 1884" is well-formed English. I'm precisely wondering if "(They) have been in use since 1884" were a better way to say what you wrote?

Comment: @Carlo_R. I mean "forewent was used as recently as 1884". So, no, it's not a better way. "As recently as 1884" should be read sarcastically.

Comment: @Barrie: I'm not sure about your interpretation of the OED (though I've done it myself). The complilers look for the earliest use of a word, but don't include the latest (obviously impossible); sometimes they say 'now obsolete' or similar, but otherwise you can't deduce much about current usage.

Comment: @TimLymington: Yeh, but 1596, and only three instances previously? Until now, I have never knowingly seen, heard or said 'for(e)went'

Comment: Both forwent and forewent, [according to Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=forewent%2Cforwent&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), still enjoy use today (albeit very little), and forwent actually seems to have surpassed forewent in recent years. It seems, perhaps, to be used more often in technical writing.

Comment: I wonder if the respondent here could elaborate on his claim that the word serves no useful purpose.  Is there another word that is equivalent and preferred?

Comment: FWIW, I think some instances of *forEwent* have a different root, *forego* meaning precede ('the foregoing would indicate...', 'foregone conclusion').

Comment: @Fixee: give up, sacrifice, surrender, do without, kick, abdandon, resign, yield, relinquish, renounce, waive, say goodbye to, cede, abjure, leave alone, leave out

Comment: @BarrieEngland: "Since I was sick yesterday, I forwent jogging."  Try all of your suggested words in its place: none works.  Try any other English word or phrase of two syllables or less.  I still am not seeing that it "serves no useful purpose" as your answer claims.

Comment: @Fixee: I can't imagine anyone saying that, other than in jest. What you would hear, at least in BrEng, would be something like 'I didn't feel well yesterday, so I could't go jogging'. In any case, my point was a generic rather than a specific one: words fall out of use when they no longer serve a purpose. The extent to which 'forgo' has actually fallen out of use could be established only by examining a number of corpora. My belief that it has done so is entirely intuitive.

Comment: I have found one recent use of this word. The relevant quote is > ...Parker studied her for a moment, not at all liking what he found, but forwent any comment. Found in *The Neutronium Alchemist* by Peter F. Hamilton. Published 20 October 1997.

Comment: I have found another recent use of the word in _Critical Mass_ by Sara Paretsky. The setting is in the coffee shop, the University of Chicago Library. > She let me buy her a cola, but I **forwent** coffee when I saw it looked like. I have no theory as to why it is used here, but it seems fitting.

Comment: Years after asking this question, I still find it fascinating: "I go, I went, I have gone" have all remained in common usage; "I forgo, I forwent, I have forgone" are likewise common except "forwent" which has been discarded for some reason.  The answer above claims it (and it alone in its family?) serves no useful purpose.

Comment: @Fixee I'll give you a one-syllable alternative to _forwent_ in that jogging example that not only means pretty much the same thing, but also sounds a lot more natural: _skipped_.

Answer (score 4):

*I suspect it's more common to say, for example, "I decided to forgo treatment" rather than "I forwent treatment." But why?*

I think there is a tendency to avoid using non-basic forms (also known as the other 'principal parts') of irregular verbs that are themselves uncommon in the present tense.  I suspect this is so because people cannot remember the proper form or find it awkward.  For example, the verb *slay* is used a lot (slaying, slays), but how often do you read *slew*?

As for your other question, people tend to cling fast to the original verbs in set phrases.  "Forego the opportunity" is perhaps the most famous one for "forego", and you will find that Google yields 33 000 instances of the past tense "for(e)went the opportunity."  So there is at least one usage of "for(e)went" that is alive and well.

Comment: Being an avid reader of such writers as Tolkien and George R.R. Martin, I'd have to say I read the word ‘slew’ fairly frequently. Can't say the same for a verb like ‘shear’, though—I can remember hearing native speakers (Irish and American alike, possibly even a Brit here or there) say it as ‘sheared’ in the past tense/participle; but I'm not sure if I've ever heard anyone apart from Stephen Fry say ‘shore’ or ‘shorn’ in natural conversation. (Granted, I do not socialise much with sheep-shearers)

Answer (score 1):

"Forwent" isn't used much because so few people know the word. Here is a message using the word that I posted today on facebook:

I added a layer to my torso and used liners in my gloves but forwent the balaclava. I would have been more comfortable with it.

Answer (score 0):

The most recent use of forwent is in Series One Episode 4 of Silicon Valley, which is a comedy and they add after using the term, "For which I forwent, yes that's a real word, one million dollars". I think if you used it now some might think it a literary allusion to that TV series.